# missing import for tweepy on vscode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, tweepy

im having problem to use tweepy on vscode, it keep reporting a missing import of tweepy and i dont know why.

on power shell shows that requirement already satisfied, and i can see the tweepy on vscode if i search it, so what is going on ?

PS C:\Windows\System32> pip install tweepy
Requirement already satisfied: tweepy in c:\users\arthu\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (4.5.0)
Requirement already satisfied: requests-oauthlib<2,>=1.0.0 in c:\users\arthu\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from tweepy) (1.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: requests<3,>=2.27.0 in c:\users\arthu\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from tweepy) (2.27.1)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<4,>=2.5 in c:\users\arthu\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from requests<3,>=2.27.0->tweepy) (2.5)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.27,>=1.21.1 in c:\users\arthu\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from requests<3,>=2.27.0->tweepy) (1.26.8)
Requirement already satisfied: charset-normalizer~=2.0.0 in c:\users\arthu\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from requests<3,>=2.27.0->tweepy) (2.0.10)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in c:\users\arthu\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from requests<3,>=2.27.0->tweepy) (2021.10.8)
Requirement already satisfied: oauthlib>=3.0.0 in c:\users\arthu\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from requests-oauthlib<2,>=1.0.0->tweepy) (3.1.1)
PS C:\Windows\System32>

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem in using tweepy in vs code
so just to be sure i installed tweepy by using `pip install tweepy` in shell terminal and
the terminal in vs code(just to be sure) and ubuntu as well after that i closed the vs code and then opened it again and it worked, hopefully it works with you